# Snowflake Cluster key on varchar column along with functions is not pruning

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have a GUID varchar field on the snowflake table and that is going to use in our joins and filter so we needed this as Cluster Key as we will have the multi terabytes of data.

so, I have been doing testing from a performance perspective, as its not good practice to have a unique key as a cluster so I cluster it with **LEFT(col,6)** but the query is not pruning.
but when I create another column with the same expression and cluster that column snowflake starts to prune.

Can someone help me understand what is happening here, or I am open to any other key consideration idea?

***Edit 1** output of select SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION( '<table_name>' )

[image]

***EDIT 2** DDL of table looks like this:

```
  create or replace TRANSIENT TABLE TEST cluster by (right(C1,6))(
    C1 VARCHAR(1000),
    C2 VARCHAR(1000),
    C3 VARCHAR(1000),
    I1 VARCHAR(1000),
    I2 VARCHAR(1000),
    P1 TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    S1 VARCHAR(1000),
    S1 TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    P2 VARCHAR(1000),
    E1 VARIANT,
    I2 TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
);
```

Comment: Please run `select SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION( '<table_name>' );` and update the question with the output.

Comment: Can you also update the question with the DDL for the table and the query you are using to test this?

Comment: That is a very small table for auto clustering, but in any event the clustering looks okay. It may not be possible to use UUIDs for partition pruning if the only filter applied to them is a join condition. Snowflake will use range pruning on joins, but since UUIDs are often random, the range will look something like 00045 to FFF34. That's going to enable a fraction of a percent of partitions clustered on UUID leading edges to be pruned, and a fraction of a percent on a table with 12 micropartitions rounds down to zero most of the time. A where clause filter will get better pruning.

Comment: @GregPavlik I tested this table with 100 GB first but as "manual reclustering" was taking time so I created a small replica table to test.
I am manually Reclustering it to test, as per the snowflake document we could use the function in the clustering key so it should work, can you please help me to know why it is not working.

Thanks for letting me know that snowflake uses range pruning to join, BTW I tested HASH(left(col)) as cluster key but the query does not prune,
but it always prunes if I create another column with these values.

Comment: This gets very detailed and would be better covered interactively. You can have your sales engineer reach out to me to schedule a meeting to discuss it if you'd like.

Comment: we will contact to you soon.

Comment: Would also help to show us the query you're using, and the explain plan.  If you have an expression in your where clause, pruning likely won't be coming into play - those have to be evaluated post expression for comparison, and therefore all records will be included for processing.